# RedirectMatch Equivalent of a Mod_Rewrite Rule for Rearranging Directory Structure

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to recreate a mod_rewrite rule in the form of a RedirectMatch directive.

First, please take a look at this mod_rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www.)?africananimals.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} zebras
RewriteRule ^(stripes|hooves)/zebras/?$ zebras/$1 [R,L]
```

The rule (written by a very helpful and knowledgeable StackOverflow contributor) tells the server to transform these four URLs:

http://africananimals.com/stripes/zebras

http://africananimals.com/hooves/zebras

http://www.africananimals.com/stripes/zebras

http://www.africananimals.com/hooves/zebras

-- into these better and more logically structured ones:

http://africananimals.com/zebras/stripes

http://africananimals.com/zebras/hooves

http://www.africananimals.com/zebras/stripes

http://www.africananimals.com/zebras/hooves

(These are not actual URLs, just examples.)

There are other websites on that hosting server, which may happen to have identical directory structure, so the first conditional ensures that a rule is only applied to the africananimals.com domain, with or without www.

The second conditional ensures that the rule is only applied when the word "zebras" is present in the URL.

The rule itself selects either "stripes" or "hooves" followed by "/zebras" or "/zebras/" and rewrites the URL, placing the previously selected item (either "stripes" or "hooves") after "zebras/" – exactly as it should be done.

**Question:** how can the same task be accomplished using RedirectMatch directive?

Being an Apache amateur, I would very much appreciate insight from a professional.

Comment: I guess something like this will do it: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(stripes|hooves)/zebras/?$ http://africananimals.com/zebras/$1`

Comment: Thank you @faa, that's just what I needed! Would you like to type it as an actual answer, so that I can select it as the best?

Comment: Okay. Thanks. I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this will do it:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(stripes|hooves)/zebras/?$ http://africananimals.com/zebras/$1
```